# pthread_create in PHP extension (in C++) function never returns

Tags: php, c++, linux, multithreading

My c++ library create a thread with pthread_create somewhere in the code. Using my library inside a stand-alone application works great, but when using it in PHP extension. 
The function never returns.

```
void* threadloop(void * param)
{
    zend_printf("B\n");
}
PHP_FUNCTION(create_thread)
{
    pthread_t othread;
    pthread_create (&othread, NULL, threadloop, NULL);
    zend_printf("A\n");
}
```

The "B" is never printed.

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using a build of PHP in which `zend_printf` is thread-safe? You should run a test -- join the thread right after creating it, and see if you get the output.

Comment: is this relevant? using for example std::cout << "hello"; not works

Comment: Wait -- `"A\n"` is printed?  Then `pthread_create` returns, because `"A\n"` occurs after `pthread_create` returns.

Comment: It is important to narrow down the problem. For example, the problem might be that the process terminated before the thread got a chance to run. You have no synchronization.

Comment: Then `pthread_create` returned. The new thread probably just never got a chance to run. You never wait for it.

Comment: pthread_create (&othread, NULL, threadloop, NULL);
    sleep(1);
    zend_printf("A\n");
is working and printing B and A

Comment: @felix46r so, do you understand what you are doing wrong now?

Comment: @felix46r so the next step is finding an answer that answers your question.  Give someone a green checkmark.

Answer (score 2):

You have a race condition between the newly-created thread printing and the process terminating. You need some kind of synchronization, such as joining the thread before allowing the process to terminate. (Using `sleep` is okay to demonstrate the problem, but never use `sleep` as a form of thread synchronization.)

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
void* threadloop(void * param)
{
  zend_printf("B\n");
}
PHP_FUNCTION(create_thread)
{
  pthread_t othread;
  auto result = pthread_create (&othread, NULL, threadloop, NULL);
  if (result != 0)
    zend_printf("Error!\n");
  zend_printf("A\n");
  void* result = nullptr;
  auto result2 = pthread_join( othread, &result );
  if (result2 != 0)
    zend_printf("Error2!\n");
}
```

where I have taken your code, added some simple error handling, and joined the produced thread to make sure it has finished.

I used some C++11 features above (`auto` and `nullptr` in particular), if they aren't supported by your compiler it should be pretty easy to replace them (what is the return value type of your `pthread_create`?)